# Docker inspect command not showing all the ENV vars

Tags: linux, docker, environment-variables, alpine-linux, docker-container

I ran an Alpine Docker container using the following command:

```
docker run -itd --env "my_env_var=test" --name mycontainer alpine
```

Now when I run the `env` command from inside the Docker container to get all the Env vars, I get the following output:

```
$ docker exec -it mycontainer /bin/sh
$ env
HOSTNAME=9de9045b5264
SHLVL=1
HOME=/root
my_env_var=test
TERM=xterm
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
PWD=/
```

So far, so good.

But when I try to get the Environment Variables using the `docker inspect` command, I see that **too many ENV vars are missing** (Only 2 of them are found):

```
$ docker inspect mycontainer
...
...
"Env": [
            "my_env_var=test",
            "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
        ],
...
...
```

Also, I used the `docker exec` command to print the ENV vars using the following command:

```
$ docker exec mycontainer /bin/sh -c env
HOSTNAME=9de9045b5264
SHLVL=1
HOME=/root
my_env_var=test
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
PWD=/
```

This time, all the ENV vars were displayed except for the `TERM=xterm`.

I observed this behaviour with centos Docker images as well. Why is it so that all the ENV vars are not getting printed using `docker inspect` or `docker exec`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because those environment variables are set by the binaries you are using to display them — here `/bin/sh`.

There are mechanisms in Linux distributions allowing you setting variables for an interactive shell, like */etc/profile* to cite [only one out of them](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell#Configuration_files).

A better command to run in order to have something closer to what your `inspect` command would give you would be:

```sh
docker exec mycontainer env
```

Which gives

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
HOSTNAME=1fbc89f485c2
my_env_var=test
HOME=/root
```

---

For the different commands that are giving you the `TERM` variable, this is caused by the `-t` option of docker:

> `--tty`, `-t`     Allocate a pseudo-TTY

We can show this using

```sh
docker exec mycontainer env
```

Which gives

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
HOSTNAME=1fbc89f485c2
my_env_var=test
HOME=/root
```

Versus

```
docker exec -t mycontainer env
```

Which gives

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
HOSTNAME=1fbc89f485c2
TERM=xterm
my_env_var=test
HOME=/root
```

---

Little side note on the usage of `docker inspect`: you can also filter the output with the `format` flag to get only the information you need:

e.g.:

```sh
docker inspect mycontainer --format "{{.Config.Env}}"
```

Gives

```json
[my_env_var=test PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin]
```

Comment: This answers all my doubts. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> Why is it so that all the ENV vars are not getting printed using docker inspect or docker exec?

Because `/bin/sh` sets them.